# Error trying to install fuse-ext2 with Homebrew

Tags: xcode, homebrew, filesystem

I have installed Homebrew and Xcode already (macOS 10.15.3). I am trying to install fuse-ext2 to have access to my ext4 disks. Thought I am close to achieve it by following this from https://libraries.io/github/alperakcan/fuse-ext2

```
$ brew install e2fsprogs m4 automake autoconf libtool
$ git clone https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2.git
$ cd fuse-ext2
$ ./autogen.sh
$ CFLAGS="-idirafter/$(brew --prefix e2fsprogs)/include -idirafter/usr/local/include/osxfuse" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix e2fsprogs)/lib" ./configure
$ make 
$ sudo make install
```

But executing 'make' generates several errors:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in fuse-ext2
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in tools
Making all in macosx
( cd ../../tools/macosx/prefpane; \
      xcodebuild; \
    )
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
make[3]: *** [prefpane] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is missing at this point?

EDIT: homebrew config

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.2.6
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 27fa87c94a6cf7be40fc8f8fc96bc7c387b7781e
Last commit: 11 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 42c65ea0af06aff75feba40bea8b357129669bb0
Core tap last commit: 2 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
CPU: quad-core 64-bit ivybridge
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 11.0 build 1100
Git: 2.21.1 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 10.15.3-x86_64
CLT: 11.3.1.0.1.1576735732
Xcode: 11.3.1
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
```

EDIT2: more outputs from Terminal:

```
gustavopi-macbook:fuse-ext2 gustavopinent$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
gustavopi-macbook:fuse-ext2 gustavopinent$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libbeidpkcs11.4.1.11.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libqucs.0.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/characteristic.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/circuit.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/compat.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/complex.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/component.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/component_id.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/components.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/config.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/constants.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/consts.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/device.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/integrator.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/logging.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/matrix.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/net.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/netdefs.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/node.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/object.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/operatingpoint.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/pair.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/precision.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/property.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/ptrlist.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/qucs_interface.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/qucs_typedefs.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/real.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/states.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/valuelist.h
  /usr/local/include/qucs-core/vector.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
  /usr/local/lib/libqucs.la

Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew cleanup`:
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.19/Resource/CIDFSubst/ipaexg.ttf
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.19/Resource/CIDFSubst/ipaexm.ttf
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.19/Resource/CIDFSubst/ipag.ttf
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.19/Resource/CIDFSubst/ipam.ttf
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.19/Resource/Font/bchb8a.pfb
  (...) a lot of pfb files
```

Comment: Can you run `brew config` in Terminal and share the output?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Shared in the post now

Comment: `brew config` looks fine to me. Can you also share the output of running `xcode-select -p` and `brew doctor`?

Comment: I updated with the outputs but had to cut a list of files because blow up the limit of the post (30k chars)

Comment: @NimeshNeema Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your XCode **make** appears to be conflicting with your GNUtils **make**.

try `sudo find / -name make` to make sure you're running the one you actually want.

Comment: This will return hundreds of answers, there is make everywhere. Thought it is executing CommandLineTools that it seems NOT part of Xcode by the error message. How do I fix it?

Comment: Try using the brew **make** by specifying the absolute path to it. Something like **/usr/bin/make** or even **.//Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/make**

Answer (score 0):

Error `tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'` means that you need to reset to the default command line tools path. To do this execute command

```
xcode-select -r
```

Comment: This will give me the same error again. There is a lot of errors in this long process. Thought this is chaotic and won't ever work in my OS, but thanks for trying to help me.